# Как установить картинку в ImageView из SD накопителя?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

На SD есть папка с изображением. У меня есть к ней путь. Как я могу по директории установить эту картинку на ImageView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам нашел решение:

```
        File image = new File(path);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```